# CSS3 Transition: Width is behaving strangely

Tags: css, css-transitions

I want to transition the width and the left margin / translateX a box so that it appears so grow from it's center.

Unfortuntely the width transition seems to be out of sync with everything else, and the element hops strangely.

Even with extremely long timings.

Can anybody help?

```
.escape {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 960px;
  background-color: #000000;
  top: 100px;
  left: 0;
  overflow: hidden; }
  .escape .container {
    width: 10000px;
    min-height: 790px;
    /*      background-color: red; */ }
  .escape .first {
    min-width: 260px;
    height: 960px;
    background: black url(../women_look_14_15_export_small.jpg) scroll no-repeat top center;
    background-size: auto 100%;
    /*      background-image: url(image_01.jpg); */
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-transition: transform 0.2s ease-out 0s;
    -moz-transition: transform 0.2s ease-out 0s;
    transition: transform 0.2s ease-out 0s;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; }
  .escape .first:hover {
    opacity: 1;
    width: 400px;
    /*      margin-left: -$hover_margin; */
    z-index: 9999;
    -webkit-transform: translateX(-70px); }
  .escape .first.expanded {
    width: 900px;
    background-color: white;
    margin-left: -400px; }
  .escape .first.collapsed {
    width: 100px; }
  .escape .left {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    background-color: red;
    top: -90px;
    color: white;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5 ease 0s;
    -moz-transition: all 1.5 ease 0s;
    transition: all 1.5 ease 0s; }
  .escape .left.show {
    top: 20px; }
  .escape .second {
    width: 90%;
    float: right;
    background-color: #fff700; }
```

The `.escape .first:hover` is the misbehaving selector…

html:

```
<div class="escape">
    <div class="container">
            <div class="first">
                00
                <div class="left">One</div>
            </div>
            <div class="first">
                01
            </div>
            <div class="first">
                02
            </div>
            <div class="first">
                03
            </div>
            <div class="first">
                04
            </div>
            <div class="first">
                05
            </div>
            <div class="first">
                06
            </div>
            <div class="first">
                07
            </div>
            <div class="first">
                08
            </div>
            <div class="first">
                09
            </div>
            <div class="first">
                10
            </div>

    </div>





    <div class="second">Second</div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

Benjamin

Comment: Do you something we could look at? HTML maybe?

Comment: Sure but I don't know if it helps much…

Added the html. Strange thing is that when I remove the transition, the hove works as expected. Only when transitioning the width it seems to transition in a strange fashion…

Comment: You do realize that the `.escape .first` selector your `transition` rule is only transitioning the `transform` property right?

Comment: Yes, had it set to all and then appeared to be moving like described.
I just removed everything apart from the width, and it seems to be that one. It's set to linear, however, it has a delay exactly the duration time. So when I set @include transition (width 1.2s linear 0s); it takes 1.2s to even start??? Why is that??

Comment: Have you looked into [CSS scale](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform)? It seems to do exactly what you want